# Is there a way to trigger all the onlick() events on a html page automatically Using the Console?

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that has a lot of onClick() Events, which on click provides access to certain file on the server.
I need to download all that content but I can't click the buttons one by one.
What my point is that is there a way to invoke these onclick events using the Browser Console, not through any other way.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try, getting all the elements and then triggering click, if you have a CSS selector to select any perticular element you can give those iplace of '*' in the below code.

```
var x=document.querySelectorAll("*");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if('click' in x[i])
  {
         x[i].click();
   }
}
```

Comment: The property is `onclick`.

Comment: No I want to check `HTMLElement.click()` so if element does not have click property then that may throw error.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were looking for all the elements that have `onclick="something()"`

Comment: Don't most elements inherit the click method from the element type, so it will never be an own property?

Answer (score 0):

You should not trigger them automatically. You could call functions from onClick.
Or if you really want to trigger them, use standard DOM function `click`

Usage of `click`

```
document.getElementById("element_id").click();
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("element_class")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click',function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    // with e.target is what ever element you want trigger
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the question was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a common class name to all the elements that take `onClick`. Lets say:

```
<body>
   <button class="clickClass">1</button>
   <button class="clickClass">2</button>
   <button class="clickClass">3</button>
</body>
```

In js, you can do:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".clickClass").forEach(function(el) {
  el.click();
});
```